# How to import common module namespaces in xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have few module namespace xquery files which were used in multiple files. I want to have the namespaces in one common xquery file and import that file whereever I want to use.

Say for example,

I have `process-lib.xqy`, `util-lib.xqy` and `query-lib.xqy`.
I used to import these in multiple files like following,

```
import module namespace util = "util" at "util-lib.xqy";
import module namespace process = "process" at "process-lib.xqy";
import module namespace query = "query" at "query-lib.xqy";
```

Now I tried to use  them in one common file named as `common-import.xqy` and import this file in multiple files.

when I tried this approach,

```
import module namespace common-import= "common-import" at "common-import.xqy";
```

It throws exception as `prefix util has no namespace binding`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: I think you're saying that common-import.xqy imports util, process, and query, then in some other XQuery module you're importing just common-import and trying to call a util namespace function. Is that correct?

Comment: yes Dave.you are  right.can we achieve this????

Comment: See dirkk's answer, that's what I was going to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, at least not in the way you want to do it and rightfully so. The [XQuery spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-module-import) doesn't allow this:

```
Module imports are not transitive—that is, importing a module provides access only to function and variable declarations contained directly in the imported module. For example, if module A imports module B, and module B imports module C, module A does not have access to the functions and variables declared in module C.
```

This is a deliberate design decision. If you want to have access in this way you could write a wrapper function for each function you want to access, e.g. in your `common-import.xqy` file you could have:

```
declare function common-import:test() { 
  util:test() 
};
```

But of course this can require a tremendous amount of wrapper functions. I would recommend you stick simply to inserting all required libraries. I see no benefit in doing otherwise.